# Find $f'(1)$ given $f(x)$ and $f(1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

**Question:**

> Let $$f(x)=\int\frac{x-1}{x+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}$$ such that $f(1)=\frac{2\pi}{3}$
>
> Then $f'(1)$ is equal to
>
> A) $0$
>
> B) $\cfrac \pi3$
>
> C) $\cfrac\pi4$
>
> D) $2$

**Attempt:**

> \begin{align}f(x)&=\int\frac{x-1}{x+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}dx\\
> f(1)&=\int0dx\\
> f(1)&=0+c\\
> &= \frac{2\pi}{3}\\
> \implies c&= \frac{2\pi}{3}
> \end{align}

I don't know what to do beyond this step. This is an indefinite integral so we cannot differentiate it. How else we bring $f'(x)$ into picture? Any hints?

Comment: It would be better if you type your question, it shows your seriousness to this question and forum.

Comment: The notation is not appropriate since $x$ in the integral is a bound variable, whereas $x$ in $f(x)$ is a free variable. From that, antiderivatives include an integration constant. Here,
$$f(x) = 2\pi/3 + \int_{1}^x \frac{t-1}{t+1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^3+t^2+t}}\, .$$
Now, you may differentiate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stipulation that $f(1)=2\pi/3$ is a red herring; it's irrelevant to the solution.  As soon as you see a relation of the form $f(x)=\int g(x)dx$, you know that $f'(x)=g(x)$.  In this case,

$$f'(x)={x-1\over (x+1)\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}}$$

and thus $f'(1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x)$ is simply the term under integration.$$f'(x)=\frac{x-1}{x+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x + x^2 + x^3}}$$

Take an example.

$$\text{Let} ~~~g(x) = \int xdx ; ~~\text{find g(1), given g(0)=0.}$$.

As you have done , it should be $$g(1) = \int 1dx= x+c$$ using $ Since g(0)=0  \implies c=0$

So, $g(1)$ should $x$, isn't it weird?

Yes, it is, because it is wrong.

By integrating , we will get $$g(x)=\frac{x^2}{2} \implies g(1)=\frac12$$

Therefore, $$f'(1)=\frac{1-1}{1+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 1^2 + 1^3}}=0$$

Remember, if :

$$f(x)=\int g(x)dx \implies f'(x)=g(x) ~; ~~$$

Comment: @HansLundmark I think it's correct now, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Does $f'(x)$ mean $\frac{df}{dx}$. Isnt $f'(x)$ then simply the integrated term, with the integration removed? ie, $\frac{x-1}{x+1}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{x + x^2 + x^3}}$ ?  Am I missing something?

Comment: As this stands (an uncertain question, asking whether you've missed something) it's more of a comment than an answer. Especially considering that the comments to the question that are already there raise the same concern.